# Kohana 3.2 multisite configuration

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

Right now I am sharing Kohana::Core between many sites on the same server based on [this tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/sharing-kohana). I would like to go one step further and share everything (Controllers, Views, Models) except configs and content. Is it possible? I am using 'table_prefix' field in database config to distinguish tables for each sites. I would like to load dynamically database config base on url parameters - I think it should work.

I was thinking about changing routes to:

```php
 Route::set('default', '(<site>(/<controller>(/<action>(/<parametr>)))))')
        ->defaults(array(
                   'controller' => 'mainpage',
                   'action' => 'index',
                   ));
```

But currently I have no idea in which place and how I should check  and load appropriate configs.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can do this,

one way:

build a Controller_Base class 
put there method before()

in this method grab the `<site>` param by use  `$this->request->param('site')`.

now you can load the config file in switch case or by the `<site>` param
by set the config name for each site as the `<site>`

now in every controller you should extends the Controller_Base
put before() method
and in this method use  parent::before()

Hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

I found the best and the most elegant solution. I moved my application to modules directory. It was rather easy. It was necessary to change bootstrap.php to init.php by removing everything except routing. Now I can use all controllers, models and views many times with standard multisite configuration.